# Opencv4Tegra performance issue

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, tegra

I am trying to create a real time panoramic video stitching application on **Jetson TK** using opencv. I have tested opencv's sample stitching_detailed.cpp on it and compared the results with and without using GPU. I stitched 30 **1240x720** images and it took about 33 seconds with GPU and 45 seconds with CPU. 
Even tough GPU results are faster but they are quite far from being real time. My objective is to stich 1240x720 with 30 FPS. What steps should I take to improve opencv's performance using GPU.
My opencv version is **2.4.12 Opencv4Tegra**

Comment: what do you mean by "gpu"? did you use the opencv gpu functions (like cuda)? OpenCV4Tegra uses the tegra (=gpu) functionality in the CPU version of the functions afair! But you should check check which functions are using tegra at all...

Comment: by gpu i mean specifying the option "try_gpu" when executing the stitching pipeline. OpenCV4Tegra is CUDA enabled and so is nVidia Jetson TK1

Comment: what I mean is that OpenCV has its own CUDA kernels, but it has some specialized tegra library function calls, too. The cuda kernels have some overhead (and afair only some weak compute capability), while the tegra library functions are extremely optimized. But since you are using the stitching pipeline (very high-level), those thoughts might have no meaning at all. And probably it isn't possible to improve the stitching pipeline's performance (easily).